# How do I use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX in SQL to return only the right part of a field contained within brackets if multiple brackets are in the field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, sql-server-2016, charindex

I have a column of data that contains varchar data and I've been trying to return only the section contained with brackets using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING :

column data: **'this is an (example)'**

I use the following code to return 'example' from the above data:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (column,  CHARINDEX('(', column)+1 ,   CHARINDEX(')', column)- CHARINDEX('(', column)-1 )
```

This works fine, however, in some instances, the data in the field has multiple occurrences of data between two brackets:

**- 'this (is) an (example)'**

This means that my code above returns 'is'.  In my data, what I want to return is the data in the right most set of brackets:

- **'this (is) an (example)'** - I would want to return **'example'**
- **'this (is) some (text)'** - I would want to return **'text'**
- **'this (is) definitely (not) a (number)'** - I would want to return **'number'**

etc

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: The terms are interchangeable, and some database systems use field instead of column. I don't think it's a necessary argument to have in stack overflow comment section though. Semantics arguments are nigh useless to begin with, honestly. OP, in addition to the database system, please include the version. Some have newer functions that could help you here.

Comment: Strangely enough, I did actually write column originally, then replaced it with field. I'm using MS SQL V16 but the solution suggested by Gordon Linoff below works.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to go also:
Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=20e3188b7426861755b1b25883be0bda)

```
select reverse(
          substring(
             reverse(str_col)
             , CHARINDEX(')', reverse(str_col))+1
             , CHARINDEX('(', reverse(str_col))-2 
          )
       )
from test;
```

Comment: This a fantastic solution, VBoka - and great DEMO!  Absolutely fantastic work!  This has actually eliminate the leading '(' that was present i the previous solution.

Comment: I am happy I can help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In all your examples, the last character is a `)`.  If this is always true, then the simplest method is probably:

```
select replace(stuff(v.str, 1, len(v.str) - charindex('(', reverse(v.str)) - 1, ''), ')', '')
from (values ('this (is) definitely (not) a (number)')) v(str);
```

A more general solution is:

```
select v.str,
       replace(stuff(v2.str, 1, len(v2.str) - charindex('(', reverse(v2.str) + '(') + 1, ''), ')', '')
from (values ('this (is) definitely (not) a (number)'),
             ('this (is) definitely (not) a (number) alas'),
             ('no parens')
     ) v(str) cross apply
     (values (left(v.str, len(v.str) - charindex(')', reverse(v.str) + ')') + 1))) v2(str);
```

Comment: Yes, in the example I'm using, the last character is ')' so the first solution will suffice (which works, however, it includes the first bracket which is easy enough to eliminate).  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the text/number itself don't include `(` or `)`, this should work too

```
select replace(reverse(left(reverse(str_col), charindex('(', reverse(str_col)) -1)),')','')
from test;
```